# When does Node's REPL get "stuck"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

Sometimes, when you type enter after a correct finished statement, the REPL waits for more :

```
> var f; function(){};
...
```

When **exactly** does that happen ? I didn't found any documentation on that.

Comment: FYI, a function declaration is not a statement and doesn't require a semi-column. The function declaration gets hoisted so you are basically writing `var f;;`. Also, `function(){}` is not a valid syntax at all in this context -> `SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

Comment: @plalx This isn't a function declaration but a function expression (no identifier).

Comment: Yeah I had not finished my comment ;) You have to wrap the function expression within `()` to make it a valid expression.

Comment: Damn... I was looking for something complex and this was just this stupid error ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is not correct. When run from a file, a syntax error is reported:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

There was a bug in REPL where in the case of a syntax error, REPL assumed the code to evaluate is not complete and would span multiple lines. Regardless of the type of syntax error.

The issue was fixed in v0.11.7 by commit [9ef9a9d](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/9ef9a9dee54a464a46739b14e8a348bec673c5a5). See the commit message for more details.